# MySQL multiple query setup

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to put two and possibly additional select queries into 1 big query for a view but having trouble. The end result should be 1 row containing the count of selected fields with two columns. Do I use a subselect for this?

Here are the first two queries:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(PIN.APP_UID) AS `Type A outstanding`
FROM PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
  WHERE
  PIN.APP_STATUS = "To_Do"
  AND
  PIN.DATE_COMPLETED IS NULL


SELECT
  COUNT(PSN.APP_UID) AS `Type B outstanding`
FROM PMT_SIGN_NORMAL PSN
  WHERE
  PSN.APP_STATUS = "To_Do"
  AND
  PSN.DATE_COMPLETED IS NULL
```

Comment: Are those two tables related in any manner?

Comment: sort of. both tables only share 1 commonality which is a wo_id field but it is not set as a constraint for either tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
    (SELECT COUNT(PIN.APP_UID)
FROM PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
WHERE PIN.APP_STATUS = "To_Do"
AND PIN.DATE_COMPLETED IS NULL) as `Type A outstanding`,


(SELECT COUNT(PSN.APP_UID)
FROM PMT_SIGN_NORMAL PSN
WHERE
PSN.APP_STATUS = "To_Do"
AND PSN.DATE_COMPLETED IS NULL) AS `Type B outstanding`
```

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly. yeh, my guess for what the subselect would have looked like was a bit far off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a sub query could do this. It would look something like the following

```
SELECT (SELECT  COUNT(PIN.APP_UID) 
        FROM PMT_INSP_NORMAL PIN
         WHERE PIN.APP_STATUS = 'To_Do'  AND PIN.DATE_COMPLETED IS NULL
        ) AS 'Type A outstanding'
     ,
     (SELECT COUNT(PSN.APP_UID) 
        FROM PMT_SIGN_NORMAL PSN
        WHERE PSN.APP_STATUS = 'To_Do' AND PSN.DATE_COMPLETED IS NULL
) AS 'Type B outstanding'
```